# Can someone help me make the transition to a new window using Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Im very new and am interested in working with windows and Tkinter. please be gentle.

here is my code that is supposed to go to a new window then open an image in that new window. However, instead of putting the image in the new window it puts it in the first window.

I think this has something to do with toplevel but i cant seem to make that work right.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk
import os

class Application(Frame):
    """ A GUI application with three buttons. """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()



    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create button, text and entry widgets"""
        self.instruction = Label(self, text = "First off what is your name?")
        self.instruction.grid(row=0, column =0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        #self.first = first

        self.name = Entry(self)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column =1, sticky=W)

        self.submit_button = Button(self, text ="Submitsss", command = self.reveal)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky =W)

        self.text = Text(self, width =35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row=3, column = 0, columnspan =2, sticky = W)

        self.ok_button = Button(self, text = "Next", command = self.go_to_2)
        self.ok_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)

    def reveal(self):
        """Display message based on the name typed in"""
        content = self.name.get()

        message = "Hello %s" %(content)

        self.text.insert(0.0, message)

    def go_to_2(self):
        self.destroy()
        #root = Tk()
        #self.newApplication = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        #self.app3 = Application2(self.newApplication)
        root.title("game")
        root.geometry("600x480")

        #root = Tk()
        #app2=Application2(root)

        self.newWindow = Tk.Toplevel()
        self.app = Application2(self.newWindow)


class Application2(Frame):
    """ A GUI application with three buttons. """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        #master.panel()
        master.title("a")
        #self.root.mainloop()
        master.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\Users\david\Pictures\sdf.jpg"))
        master.panel = Label(root, image = master.img)
        master.panel.pack()
    def create_widgets(self):


        self.submit_button = Button(self, text ="Submit")
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky =W)
        self.name = Entry(self)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column =1, sticky=W)
        self.ok_button = Button(self, text = "Next", command = self.go_to_3)
        self.ok_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)
    def go_to_3(self):
        root = Tk()

        app2=Application3(root)
    #def create_picture(self):




class Application3(Frame):
    """ A GUI application with three buttons. """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = Button(self, text = "ass")
        root.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.title("game")
root.geometry("600x480")




app = Application(root)
root.mainloop() 

#app2= Application2(root)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
       # main()
```

Answer (score 1):

To create another toplevel widget, use the `Toplevel` command. Don't try calling `Tk()` again.

For instance the following produces two toplevel Tk windows on screen:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
dlg = tk.Toplevel(root)
```

One significant difference between the top toplevels is if you destroy `root` then you unload Tk and destroy all Tk windows. However, a `Toplevel` widget can be destroyed without affecting the rest of the application so is suitable for use as a dialog or other separate window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This will make a window and you can push a button to pop up a new window. There is already a label on that window as an example.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the window and recreate the widgets you want, you can try this code.

```
# import the required modules
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as ttkb

# create a window 
root = ttkb.Window(themename= 'darkly')
root.title('NAVIS')
root.geometry('1200x600')
root.resizable(0,0)

def ViewHome(parent):
    for widget in parent.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    # parent.delete('all')
    mylabel = ttkb.Label(parent, text='This is home')
    mylabel.pack()
    parent.update()

def ViewGPS(parent):
    for widget in parent.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    gpslabel = ttkb.Label(parent, text='This is GPS')
    gpslabel.pack()
    parent.update()

buttonFrame = ttkb.Frame(root, height = 500, width = 50, padding = 50)
dashbookFrame = ttkb.Frame(root, height = 500, width = 900, padding = 30,)
buttonFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)
dashbookFrame.grid(row=0, column=1)
myCanvas = Canvas(dashbookFrame)
myCanvas.pack()
myCanvas.delete()
home_button = ttkb.Button(buttonFrame, command= lambda: ViewHome(myCanvas),
                    text = "HOME", 
                    width = 15, 
                    style = 'light.Outline.TButton')
gps_button = ttkb.Button(buttonFrame, command= lambda: ViewGPS(myCanvas),
                    text = "GPS", 
                    width = 15, 
                    style = 'light.Outline.TButton')
home_button.pack()
gps_button.pack()
ViewHome(myCanvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Here I use simple coding. I hope this works for anyone who needs help and that someone can update this for the better.